# Flutter debug console not show print on real device

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am running flutter on a real device and I realize that print() does not work on a physical device. They only work for a maximum of a minute and then it doesn't print anything else. Does anybody know what is it due to? In emulator it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter typically warns against using print and is event a rule in the linter. I have found that using the logger library or using `debugPrint()` has fixed this on physical devices.

Comment: Hi neither the logger library nor debugPrint() works for me, it only works for me as soon as I start the project then nothing at all

Comment: Do they appear when you run with debug mode?